# PHP insert into database en check errors

Tags: php, postgresql

Hi I'm doing a small project for learning php, and I wrote a few functions :

In the this piece of code, I basically check all the fields in my form and change values in a hash from false to true if they are filled in, at the end I loop the hash, and add the key (which is the error) to the array if its value is false.

```
function testBabysitterForAllElements(){
         global $db;
         $errorArray;

         $naamarray["naam"]=false;
         $naamarray["voornaam"]=false;
         $naamarray["adres"]=false;
         $naamarray["woonplaats"]=false;
         $naamarray["postcode"]=false;
         $naamarray["telefoonnummer"]=false;
         $naamarray["geboortedatum"]=false;
         $naamarray["adres"]=false;
         $naamarray["wachtwoord"]=false;
         $naamarray["email"]=false;

         if(isset($_POST['element_1'])){
            $naamarray["naam"]=true;        
         }

         if(isset($_POST['element_2'])){
            $naamarray["voornaam"]=true;        
         }

         if(isset($_POST['element_3'])){
            $naamarray["adres"]=true;       
         }

         if(isset($_POST['element_4'])){
            $naamarray["woonplaats"]=true;      
         }


         if(isset($_POST['element_5'])){
            $naamarray["postcode"]=true;        
         }

         if(isset($_POST['element_6'])){
            $naamarray["telefoonnummer"]=true;      
         }

         if(isset($_POST['element_7'])){
            $naamarray["email"]=true;       
            connectToDB();
            $sql='SELECT inlognaam FROM  kauffman.login WHERE inlognaam like \''.$_POST['element_7'].'\';';
            $rows=$db->queryRow($sql);
            if($rows){
                array_push($errorArray,"email adres is reeds geregistreerd.");
            }
         }


         if(isset($_POST['element_8_1']) && isset($_POST['element_8_2']) && isset($_POST['element_8_3'])){
            $naamarray["geboortedatum"]=true;       
         }

         if(isset($_POST['element_10']) && isset($_POST['element_10_1'])){
            $naamarray['wachtwoord']=true;
         }


         foreach($naamarray as $key => $value){
                if($value == false){
                    array_push($errorArray,$key);
                }
         }

         if(!empty($errorArray)){return $errorArray;}

    }
```

Here I add the fields to the DB, it calls the previous function to check if all fields are filled in.

```
    function babysitterToevoegenAanDB(){

    global $db;
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $errorArray=testBabysitterForAllElements();
        echo $errorArray;
    $succes=('succesvol toegevoegd');
        $result;
        if(!empty($errorArray)){
            connectToDB();

            $sql = "INSERT into kauffman.login(inlognaam,functie,paswoord) VALUES ('".antiInjectie($_POST['element_7'])."','gezin','".pwHashGenerator(antiInjectie($_POST['element_10_1']))."');";
            $sql2 = 'SELECT serialKey from kauffman.login WHERE inlognaam='.antiInjectie($_POST['element_7']).';'  ;

            $result= $succes;
        }else{
            $result= $errorArray;
        }
        echo $result;
    }
}
```

Here I create my form that also has the `babysitterToevoegenAanDB()` function. This and the form are returned and can be called on a page.

```
function babysitterForm(){
    return  babysitterToevoegenAanDB().'        <form id="babysitForm" class="appnitro"  method="post" action="'.htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'">
                    <div class="form_description">
            <h2>Babysitter</h2>
            <p>Gelieve je hier in te schrijven als babysitter</p>
        </div>                      
            <ul >

                    <li id="li_1" >
        <label class="description" for="element_1">Naam </label>
        <div>
              <input id="element_1" name="element_1" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="'.
    ((isset($_POST['element_1']))? htmlentities($_POST['element_1']):'')
    . '"/>
        </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_1"><small>Voer uw naam in.</small></p> 
        </li>       <li id="li_2" >
        <label class="description" for="element_2">Voornaam </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_2" name="element_2" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="'.((isset($_POST['element_2']))? htmlentities($_POST['element_2']):'').'"/> 
        </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_2"><small>Vul uw voornaam in.</small></p> 
        </li>       <li id="li_3" >
        <label class="description" for="element_3">Adres </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_3" name="element_3" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="'.((isset($_POST['element_3']))? htmlentities($_POST['element_3']):'').'"/> 
        </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_3"><small>vul uw straat en huisnummer in.</small></p> 
        </li>       <li id="li_4" >
        <label class="description" for="element_4">Woonplaats </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_4" name="element_4" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="'.((isset($_POST['element_4']))? htmlentities($_POST['element_4']):'').'"/> 
        </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_4"><small>vul uw woonplaats in.</small></p> 
        </li>       <li id="li_5" >
        <label class="description" for="element_5">Postcode </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_5" name="element_5" class="element text small" type="text" maxlength="255" value="'.((isset($_POST['element_5']))? htmlentities($_POST['element_5']):'').'"/> 
        </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_5"><small>Vul uw Postcode hier in</small></p> 
        </li>       <li id="li_6" >
        <label class="description" for="element_6">telefoonnummer </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_6" name="element_6" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="'.((isset($_POST['element_6']))? htmlentities($_POST['element_6']):'').'"/> 
        </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_6"><small>Vul uw telefoonnummer in.</small></p> 
        </li>       <li id="li_7" >
        <label class="description" for="element_7">email </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_7" name="element_7" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="'.((isset($_POST['element_7']))? htmlentities($_POST['element_7']):'').'"/> 
        </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_7"><small>vul uw email in.</small></p> 
        </li>       <li id="li_8" >
        <label class="description" >Geboortedatum </label>
        <span>
            <input id="element_8_1" name="element_8_1" class="element text" size="2" maxlength="2" value="'.((isset($_POST['element_8_1']))? htmlentities($_POST['element_8_1']):'').'" type="text"> /
            <label for="element_8_1">MM</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="element_8_2" name="element_8_2" class="element text" size="2" maxlength="2" value="'.((isset($_POST['element_8_2']))? htmlentities($_POST['element_8_2']):'').'" type="text"> /
            <label for="element_8_2">DD</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="element_8_3" name="element_8_3" class="element text" size="4" maxlength="4" value="'.((isset($_POST['element_8_3']))? htmlentities($_POST['element_8_3']):'').'" type="text">
            <label for="element_8_3">YYYY</label>
        </span>

        <li id="li_10" >
        <label class="description" for="element_10">Wachtwoord </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_10" name="element_10" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="'.((isset($_POST['element_10']))? htmlentities($_POST['element_10']):'').'"/> 
            <input id="element_10_1" name="element_10_1" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="'.((isset($_POST['element_10_1']))? htmlentities($_POST['element_10_1']):'').'"/> 
        </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_10"><small>Vul uw wachtwoord twee maal in. Hierdoor voorkomt men typfouten door validatie.</small></p> 
        </li>       



            <li id="li_9" >
        <label class="description" for="element_9">Opmerkingen </label>
        <div>
            <textarea id="element_9" name="element_9" class="element textarea medium" ></textarea> 
        </div> 
        </li>

                    <li class="buttons">
                <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="206335" />

                <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </li>
            </ul>
        </form> ';
}
```

What basically happens is :

1. I call the last function babysitteForm which shows a form to apply
2. BabysitterForm includes the babySitterToevoegenAanDB function that checks if submit is set
3. If so it checks all the fields if there are errors it has to return an array with errors

However if I click submit without filling anyhting in, there is nothing added to the errorArray.

Comment: Please condense your code. Nobody is going to read through the couple hundred lines of unformatted stuff.

Comment: If I knew a way to write it shorter I would, I added some documentation, but if you know a short way to check all the fields of a form please enlighten me because it would save me a lot of coding work :)

Comment: You really need to use a form library and a decent ORM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its normal that nothing gets added to your error array. 
The function isset($_POST['anything']) will only check if that field is set in your post var.

The post var gets filled up by your form.

Basicly, if your form contains 7 input fields, all these input fields their value will be placed into
$_POST.

A print of your $_POST var would be something like:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

result:

```
array('element_1'=>'','element_2'=>'' ...
```

so your isset function will check if the value 'element_x' is set, wich it is, it just contains nothing.

u need to re-write your checks so they check the content, not the existance. Isset is only of
use when checking f.e. $_GET vars if u are not sure they are set and not post vars in a form (since these will always be set).

I would suggest re-writing your checks in the form of:

```
     $naamarray["naam"]=true;
     $naamarray["voornaam"]=true;
     $naamarray["adres"]=true;
     $naamarray["woonplaats"]=true;
     $naamarray["postcode"]=true;
     $naamarray["telefoonnummer"]=true;
     $naamarray["geboortedatum"]=true;
     $naamarray["adres"]=true;
     $naamarray["wachtwoord"]=true;
     $naamarray["email"]=true;


     if($_POST['element_1'] == ""){
            $naamarray["naam"]=false;        
     }
```

do this for all your checks. 
also reverse your foreach loop:

```
foreach($naamarray as $key => $value){
            if($value == true){
                array_push($errorArray,$key);
            }
     }
```

I also have some doubts with the returning of the function before your form. I think its clearer
to create a function and just include the php page instead of this.

then u would get code like:

```
require_once('inc/functions.php');
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
  babysitterToevoegenAanDB();
} else {
  babysitterForm();
}
```

And the final tip: give your input field clear names, not just element_x ... .